# concatenate each row with another to form a stack of row in new column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table with one column and the values are given below

```
Table
------------
Ind
Pak
SL


Output
------------
Ind VS Pak
Ind VS SL
SL VS Pak
```

Output should be each row as a string in a single column mentioned above.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: @wewesthemenace...i have added a image for sample data and required output..kindly help me to get this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE to get the desired results:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Team VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Data VALUES ('Ind'), ('Pak'), ('SL')

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Team,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Team) AS RowNum
    FROM @Data
)
SELECT
    R1.Team + ' VS ' + R2.Team AS [Output]
FROM CTE R1
    INNER JOIN CTE R2
        ON R1.RowNum < R2.RowNum
```

Output:

```
Output
---------------
Ind VS Pak
Ind VS SL
Pak VS SL
```

You don't necessarily need the CTE, but I prefer to avoid joining on VARCHAR values out of habit.

```
SELECT
    R1.Team + ' VS ' + R2.Team AS [Output]
FROM @Data R1
    INNER JOIN @Data R2
        ON R1.Team < R2.Team
```